# AngularJS: ng-model not getting updated in UI

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, calendar

[image]

Hi I have a calender in my UI

```
     <select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration" required ui-
     select2="select2DurationSettings" ng-model="duration" ng-
     change="loadSensoryEvents()">
```

This duration value is not getting updated

This is my JS file

```
     if(filterStateService.getQuery()){
                filterStateService.setDefaultDuration(filterStateService.getDefaultDuration());
                $scope.duration = filterStateService.getDefaultDuration();  
         }
```

M updating this $scope.duration value but this value is not getting updated in my UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use object and declare  object in controller

```
$scope.selected = {};
```

`HTML`

```
<select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration" required ui-
 select2="select2DurationSettings" ng-model="selected.duration" ng-
change="loadSensoryEvents()">
```